# Difference between brute force and Euclidean algorithms for finding GCD

Tags: algorithm, brute-force, greatest-common-divisor

Why is consecutive integer checking algorithm for finding GCD considered brute force, but Euclidean algorithm is not? I am just confused about it. Is it because we are checking one by one?

Comment: What is Euclid? Please, provide a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

*Brute-force* algorithms try every candidate solution that could be tried, see which one fits, and return its findings as the answer. For example, a brute-force GCD algorithm would start with the smaller of the two numbers, and continue down to `1`, examining every single possibility, one by one, on its way down.

In contrast, Euclidean algorithm does not go one by one: it makes jumps, sometimes pretty significant ones. Moreover, it does not check each possible number to be a solution to the GCD problem at each step: its ending condition is rather different from a typical brute-force solution, which is to check if the current candidate is a solution to the problem, and stop when the answer is "yes". Euclidean algorithm checks a different condition, namely, `b != 0`, to decide on whether to continue or not.

These two distinctions (large steps and a different stopping condition) make the Euclidean algorithm different from brute-force algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force search involves trying every (reasonable) possibility.  Euclid's algorithm only checks a very small subset of those possibilities.